# Devise - Invalidate user session if the same user logs in from a different browser/machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a scenario where i need to restrict users from having only one active session at a time. Mine is a rails3 application and uses devise for authentication. I'm interested in keeping only the latest user session active. i.e., if a user logs in while there is another session active for the same username, i want to inactivate the older session and allow the recent one. Is there a way, in devise, to get hold of user sessions and invalidate them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can track a particular user's session by storing a unique token specific to that user in the database.

Create a migration to add the field for storing the token. I assume the devise model is User.

```
class AddSignInTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :current_sign_in_token, :string
  end
end
```

Add the following code to `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :invalidate_simultaneous_user_session, :unless => Proc.new {|c| c.controller_name == 'sessions' and c.action_name == 'create' }

  def invalidate_simultaneous_user_session
    sign_out_and_redirect(current_user) if current_user && session[:sign_in_token] != current_user.current_sign_in_token
  end

  def sign_in(resource_or_scope, *args)
    super
    token = Devise.friendly_token
    current_user.update_attribute :current_sign_in_token, token
    session[:sign_in_token] = token
  end
end
```

`sign_in(resource_or_scope, *args)` is a devise hook that will be called every time the user logs in.

`invalidate_simultaneous_user_session` will log out the current user if another instance of the current user logs in. This will ensure that only one session is active for a user at any instance of time.

`invalidate_simultaneous_user_session` filter should be skipped for the user login action to update the newly logged in user's token. I am not happy with using a Proc to skip the filter based on controller name and action. If you have already overridden devise's `sessions_controller`, then include `skip_before_filter :check_simultaneous_user_session` inside that controller and you can get rid of the Proc!

Hope this helps..

Comment: I think you need an extra ```=``` in ```c.action_name = 'create'``` to not assign but compare the action name. I.e. so it becomes: ```c.action_name == 'create'```

Answer (score 3):

For updated devise for rails 4,
you may change the code according to this

http://pastebin.com/p6mvC8T3