# How to invalidate specific session at logout in Rails /w Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I want to invalidate the session when a user logs out using Devise, i have a callback to catch when a user logs out, for more protection against session hijacking.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def sign_out(*args)
    super(*args)
    reset_session
  end
end
```

My understanding was that this would remove the session info stored on the server side, therefore invalidating it.

However I can still login using the session id I got before signing out. 
Am I misunderstanding how it works? I only want to invalidate just this session, not all of them.

I am using the default for session_store.

Comment: where are you getting the `session_id` from? also, what other session specific custom code have you added?

Comment: I was under the impression that reset_session did not require the session_id to be acquired, I have not added any custom code that would affect session values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some googling and meditating, I came apon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359730/devise-invalidate-user-session-if-the-same-user-logs-in-from-a-different-brows), which could be modified to fit my needs,

all I did was

application_controller.rb

```
  def sign_out(*args)
    current_user.update_attribute(:current_sign_in_token, "")
    super
  end
```

which will invalidate the sign_in_token, thus invalidating the session, so hijacking the session id will still get you kicked out.

Comment: I guess that method was removed. I am seeing this error:
[8] pry(#<SessionsController>)> current_user.update_attribute(:current_sign_in_token, "")
NoMethodError: undefined method `current_sign_in_token=' for #<User:0x00007f8bf104b4e0>