# How to prevent a session replay attack with Rails and Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, session-replay

I am working on a Rails app that recently went through a security audit, and one of the issues they came up with is that if the user gets the "session_id" from another users cookie, he is able to log in as that user. Is it possible to prevent this? How would I do it with my current setup?

Rails 3.2.12
devise (2.1.2)

My `config/initializers/session_store.rb` is

```
MyApp::Application.config.tap do |config|
  config.session_store :active_record_store, config.session_options
end
```

Force SSL is enabled on production

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

I looked at [Rails 4 Encrypted Cookie Replay Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337152/rails-4-encrypted-cookie-replay-attack) but since mine is using active record for sessions, not sure I can do the same.

I tried to add `:session_limitable` from [Devise security extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension/blob/master/lib/devise_security_extension/hooks/session_limitable.rb), but it appears to be doing something else altogether.

To quote the security test result

**Mitigate session replaying by ensuring that only 1 login is active at a time.** -- able to login as another user just by changing the "_session_id" cookie

Comment: The [Ruby on Rails Security Guide][1] explains what the Session id is used for and why it's not trivial to 'just change' it.
  [1]: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Comment: AFAIK devise ensure that `session_id` is reset after every succesfully login