# Disable Single user multi login rails with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, session-cookies

I was trying to  disable multi login for single user using  devise authentication  and came up with this solution.

I used `active record` `session store`, so that I can access all user session by their ID. Changed initializer `session_store.rb` to

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

added field session_id to user table and created model for session(session.rb)

rails migration:

```
rails g migration add_session_id_to_users session_id:integer
```

`session.rb`:

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Since, devise gem using warden I set callback `after_authentication` to check user session.

`user.rb`:

```
class << self
  def delete_session(session_id)
    begin
      session = Session.where("session_id=?",session_id)
      session.delete_all
    rescue => e

    end
  end
end

Warden::Manager.after_authentication do |user, auth, opts|
  unless user.session_id == ""
    auth.logout
    User.delete_session(user.session_id)
    user.session_id = ""
    user.save
    throw(:warden, :message => "User already logged in, try again wil singout from other machine")

  end
end
```

This callback will alert when user already logged in.

I was storing user session id in `application_controller` `before_filter` (`aplication_helper.rb`)

```
before_action :save_session

def save_session
  if user_signed_in? && current_user.session_id == ""
    current_user.session_id =  request.session_options[:id]
    current_user.save
  end
end
```

I was getting session ID by `request.session_options[:id]`.

This setup works fine without any problem. Guys can you please share your suggestion on this implementation. Any potential problem will occur by this solution?

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question,

[Devise - Invalidate user session if the same user logs in from a different browser/machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359730/devise-invalidate-user-session-if-the-same-user-logs-in-from-a-different-brows)

The basic idea is the same, differently implemented.

Personally like it since its all neatly in the controller rather than in the model.